# Save Plotly user graphical input as workspace variable in R

Tags: r, plot, plotly, interactive

I want to create graphs that are both interactive and allow user input to be saved to workspace in R.

So far, I love the interactive plots created by `plotly`, however, I haven't figured a way that allows users to save where they clicked or selected in the plot as workspace variables.

From my search online, I am aware of functions like `locator`, `identifier` or `grid.locator`. But I don't think these functions work in `plotly`'s interactive plots. I am also aware of `event_data` in `plotly` that works in Shiny. But I don't think it has the functionality to save the 'event' into workspace.

What I am looking for is something equivalent of `getCursorInfo` in Matlab.

Much appreciated if you could solve my problem!